# Calculate Average/mean() of a column in Python/Pandas/Numpy based on a different values in another column

Tags: pandas, if-statement, average, mean

I'd like to calculate an average of a column using pandas based on different numbers in another column.

I have two columns A,B: I'd like to have an extra column showing the average of B when values of A are between => 0 and < 20 , =>20 and <40, =>40 and <60, =>60 and <80 , =>80 and <100 and so on.. 100 as a maximum is an example .. lets say until the max number column A which could be 20000

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpZLO.png)

I have tried using an if statement but that only works for limited values, what about if I have 20000 as my max value and want the average for a range = 5 for A values?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyAkm.png)

Comment: make example to text or code not image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut` + `groupby.transform`:

```
bins = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 101]

df['C'] = df['B'].groupby(pd.cut(df['A'], bins=bins, right=False)).transform('mean')
```

If you want to generate the bins programmatically:

```
import numpy as np

MAX = 100
STEP = 20
bins = np.arange(0, MAX+1, STEP)
bins[-1] += 1
```

Comment: Hi this works .. thanks  i have a similar problem .. you should be able to know this easily. This is another post .. What can we do if there are different bins for different groups.. in your answer we only take into account that the bin is the same.. what happens when bins change from group id to group id  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75751237/calculating-the-mean-of-different-grouped-values-using-np-arange-and-pd-cut-hav

Comment: I'll leave this one as well .. this one explains it better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752435/calculate-average-mean-for-grouped-values-using-np-arange-and-pd-cut-with-differ